# Ubuntu 18.04 with Intel 10th Gen Graphics - Can't Change Color Profiles

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell, intel-graphics, firmware

I got a new laptop a few days ago, a Dell Inspiron 15 3000. In my country, you can't get the developer edition (with Ubuntu preinstalled), so I settled for the one with Windows 10. I swiftly installed Ubuntu, which worked fantastically, except that I couldn't change the brightness, or the color profile, or turn Night Light on.

After some searching I discovered that my graphics card (integrated) was not being used, and the CPU was rendering graphics. I then tried changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"`. This fixed the problem of `llvmpipe` being the graphics, and switched it to `Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics (Ice Lake 8x8 GT2)`.

After this, I could change the brightness, but I still couldn't change the color profile or activate Night Light. There was also a thin white line that would irregularly flash at the top of my screen (couldn't be screenshotted).

My only idea is that it might be something to do with the newness of my graphics (10th gen)? I have almost no experience with firmware, so help would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, here's the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    47.10  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And the output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
ccm                    20480  6
arc4                   16384  2
bnep                   24576  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
wl                   6447104  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
hid_multitouch         28672  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          49152  6
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           86016  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
dell_laptop            20480  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             241664  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
ath10k_pci             40960  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ath10k_core           438272  1 ath10k_pci
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mac80211              819200  1 ath10k_core
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd                    86016  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
idma64                 20480  0
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
cfg80211              679936  4 wl,ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
soundcore              16384  1 snd
btusb                  49152  0
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
uvcvideo               94208  0
bluetooth             557056  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              204800  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mei_me                 40960  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
joydev                 28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
ecdh_generic           28672  1 bluetooth
mei                   106496  1 mei_me
media                  53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  1 int3403_thermal
intel_hid              20480  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_pad              184320  0
acpi_tad               16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  3
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 28672  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               40960  1
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
i915                 1826816  26
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
kvmgt                  28672  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
vfio_mdev              16384  0
mdev                   24576  2 kvmgt,vfio_mdev
vfio_iommu_type1       28672  0
vfio                   32768  3 kvmgt,vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
aesni_intel           372736  6
kvm                   647168  2 kvmgt,kvm_intel
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
psmouse               151552  0
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
nvme                   45056  3
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   483328  18 drm_kms_helper,i915
r8169                  86016  0
ahci                   40960  0
nvme_core              94208  5 nvme
realtek                20480  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    28672  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
i2c_hid                28672  0
hid                   126976  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
pinctrl_icelake        24576  0
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_icelake
```

Please tell me if you need any more command outputs. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Older thread, not sure if it still applies. Start at last post & work forward. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195650

Comment: Hmm. That seems to be just to do with brightness, I have fixed the brightness issue, now it's color profile that still don't work. Also, I thought Ubuntu didn't use xorg.conf anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I had a think about Intel's 10th Gen systems, and realised they were released in 2019. Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier just don't support them. Ubuntu 19.10 supports them perfectly. If anybody else has this problem, upgrade to 19.10, it fixes everything. I did a clean reinstall because I hadn't done anything on the system yet, so I'm not sure if an upgrade from within 18.04 will work. Thank you to all those who assisted me!